# ng-if condition is not working in directive template

Tags: html, angularjs, css

I am facing with a problem when checking ng-if condition in a custom directive.Actually, i am binding response and checking condition in template.Here, it is not checking condition and displaying both font-awesome icons.

```
    Html code:

    <mydirective ng-repeat="Activiy in dDetails.activiy | orderBy:'$index':true | limitTo: limit as results"  n="{{Activiy.auditlog}}
     m="{{Activiy.activityStatus}}"></mydirective>

    Directive code:

    app.directive("mydirective", function(){
          return {
            restrict: "EA",
            scope: {
              n: "@",
              m: "@"      
            },
            template: "<span>{{n}}</span><span ng-if= 'm' == 'SUCCESS'><i class='fa fa-check' style='color: green;'></i></span><span ng-if= 'm' !='SUCCESS'><i class='fa fa-close' style='color: red;'></i></span><br>",

            link: function(scope){
              //console.log("foo: " + scope.m + " loaded");
            }
          };
        });
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
    This is how it looks in screen shot.Actually it should show only one icon if the response is success it should show green mark.if it is failed it should show red cross mark.

```
Can you please correct my code.

Thanks in Advance.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FUuv.png
```

This is how it looks in screen shot.Actually it should show only one icon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you are referring to variables in the scope you don't use quotes. If you put quotes will be interpreted like a string. Try something like this:

```
app.directive("mydirective", function(){
  return {
    restrict: "EA",
    scope: {
      n: "@",
      m: "@"      
    },
    template: '<span>{{n}}</span><span ng-if="m == \'SUCCESS\'"><i class="fa fa-check" style="color: green;"></i></span><span ng-if="m !=\'SUCCESS\'><i class="fa fa-close" style="color: red;"></i></span><br>',

    link: function(scope){
      //console.log("foo: " + scope.m + " loaded");
    }
  };
});
```